# FULL OUTER JOIN is not working

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

I need to return all vendors regardless of whether there has been a purchase from that vendor. The query is currently only returning records where the vendor had a purchase.

```
    SELECT vendors.NAME, 
       Iif([fundingsourceid] = 10, [amount], 0)        AS Credit, 
       Iif(( [fundingsourceid] = 2 ) 
            OR ( [fundingsourceid] = 3 ), [amount], 0) AS EBT, 
       Iif([fundingsourceid] = 4, [amount], 0)         AS [Match], 
       cardpurchases.updateddate 
FROM   vendors 
       FULL OUTER JOIN cardpurchases 
                    ON cardpurchases.vendorid = vendors.vendorid 
       LEFT JOIN cardfundings 
              ON cardpurchases.cardfundingid = cardfundings.cardfundingid 
       INNER JOIN marketevents 
               ON cardpurchases.marketeventid = marketevents.marketeventid 
       INNER JOIN markets 
               ON marketevents.marketid = markets.marketid 
WHERE  (cardpurchases.updateddate >= '10/22/2014' OR cardpurchases.updateddate IS NULL)
   AND (cardpurchases.updateddate < '10/23/2014' OR cardpurchases.updateddate IS NULL)
   AND (markets.marketid = 47 OR markets.marketid IS NULL)
ORDER  BY vendors.NAME
```

Comment: It "isn't working" because even if you are using a `FULL JOIN` at first, you are then doing an `INNER JOIN` taking into account only columns from **one** of those tables and you are also using `WHERE` conditions on a column from one of those tables.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the definitions of the different type of JOINS as what you are looking to achieve doesn't require a FULL JOIN and if you ran the query without the WHERE clause you see it would bring you all vendors and all card purchases, which intersect or not. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have specified a FULL OUTER JOIN later in your query you are restricting the resultset based on columns in the cardpurchases table which is causing vendors which have no cardpurchases to disappear.

You can do either of the following:

```
WHERE
((cardpurchases.updateddate >= '10/22/2014'
    AND cardpurchases.updateddate < '10/23/2014')
        OR cardpurchases.updateddate IS NULL)           
 AND markets.marketid = 47
```

Or

```
FROM   vendors 
   LEFT JOIN cardpurchases 
       ON cardpurchases.vendorid = vendors.vendorid
          AND cardpurchases.updateddate >= '10/22/2014'
          AND cardpurchases.updateddate < '10/23/2014')
```

Comment: @LucianoLipari Did you read my previous comment?, it doesn't work because you are also using an `INNER JOIN`, with the `ON` condition depending only on a column from `cardpurchases`

Comment: As stated, you need to change your INNER JOINS to LEFT JOINS

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for `NULL`s in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE  (cardpurchases.updateddate >= '10/22/2014' OR cardpurchases.updateddate IS NULL)
       AND (cardpurchases.updateddate < '10/23/2014' OR cardpurchases.updateddate IS NULL)
       AND (markets.marketid = 47 OR markets.marketid IS NULL)
```

You also should use parentheses to control the join so that the later `INNER JOIN`s don't poison it:

```
FROM   vendors 
       FULL OUTER JOIN (cardpurchases 
              LEFT JOIN cardfundings 
                     ON cardpurchases.cardfundingid = cardfundings.cardfundingid 
              INNER JOIN marketevents 
                      ON cardpurchases.marketeventid = marketevents.marketeventid 
              INNER JOIN markets 
                      ON marketevents.marketid = markets.marketid)
       ON cardpurchases.vendorid = vendors.vendorid
```

That's only partial, since you'll experience the same issue with the `LEFT JOIN` as you do with the `FULL`.

Comment: @LucianoLipari Ah, didn't read the entire join.  There's an issue with your join ordering.  Use parentheses to control it.